# Daily FX price data from yahoo finance seems to have dates that are off by i day

Tags: finance, yahoo-finance, bloomberg

When i go to the GBPUSD=X 1m chart page of yahoo finance i see the following which broadly matches the chart i see from from bloomberg except the dates in the yahoo finance chart are 1 day offset (later) than the dates from the bloomberg chart.

[image]

[image]

This issue also appears in the daily table data which is my main concern as it means the data i down load from yahoo finance is essentially wrong.

[image]

Do you know how i can fix this issue?

I am browsing from central Europe as this may be relevant.

I Have tried to look for a way of changing time zones but haven't found a way.

Comment: FX market don't "close" everyday, so the "close" price is just the price at a certain time of the day. I suspect they don't use the same convention.

Comment: The field is called "close" so i would expect it to represent price for the end of day which the Bloomberg price seems to do.

Answer (score 1):

As @assylias wrote, FX trades 24h a day and there is no such thing as a close. All you see are artificial snapshots at some point in time. FX trading is decentralized and takes place through transactions at brokerages, over-the-counter (OTC) markets, or via the interbank system, rather than centralized exchanges.

You can look up the details on the [yahoo website](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/exchanges-data-providers-yahoo-finance-sln2310.html):  the source for fx rates is ICE Data Services.

[image]

With regards to ICE, you can look these details up on their [website](https://www.icmarkets.com/global/en/trading-pricing/trading-hours#:%7E:text=The%20trading%20hours%20for%20all,server%20time%20to%2023%3A57.).

IC Markets’ server time and charts are GMT + 2 or GMT + 3 (when daylight savings is in effect). The trading hours for all currency pairs is 00:01 server time to 23:59 server time daily (23:57 on Friday).

With regards to Bloomberg, there are numerous FX rates that you can find historically. Some details

- `ALLQ` for example shows all quotes (that your institution has access to). There will be a large amount of banks and brokers quoting bid and ask to Bloomberg.
- Bloomberg curates these quotes (all, not just the ones you can see) based on two different methods (CMPN and BGN), where CMPN stands for composite New York, and BGN for Bloomberg Generic New York.
- Historically, the timing of the snapshot (New York, London - BGNL/CMPL, Tokyo BGNT/CMPT etc.) can also be set and details and white papers can be found on `QFX` and `XDF`.
- [BFIX](https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies/fx-fixings) is a fixing that is available in 30 minute intervals. These quotes also show as different days for the same 24h period (on HP or the API) because you move over the artificial snapshots time that counts as a closing time. For example BFIX F173 shows on HP the day after the date shown on the BFIX screen. There is a warning written on the BFIX screen stating that values after 17:00 reflect the next trading day. So the values for any fixing after the 5pm cut will show up on the next day on HP, despite it being from the previous calendar day.
- Bloomberg also offers BGNE (e stand for executable), which is directly derived from executable quotes on FXGO (Bloomberg's FX trading platform), whereas the other quotes are purely indicative.

All of these will show you different snapshots at different times and different values. With Yahoo, it ultimately depends on your machines time zone settings. If you try for example UTC+1 vs UTC-5 you will see the difference in dates.

[image]